# Question on a step in a proof regarding complex roots of unity powers

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, summation

Given that I have the expression

$$N^{k-1}k!\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}w_N^{-nk}e^{\frac{w_N^{n+m}x}{N}}$$

and given that $N=2m$, The next line of the proof states that the above is equal to

$$N^{k-1}k!\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}w_N^{-nk}w_N^{mk}e^{\frac{w_N^{n}x}{N}}$$

Now i know that we have $-w_N^n=w_N^{n+m}$ given that $N$ is even.  this is just negative complex numbers which rotate complex numbers 180 degrees.  But why, given what I know here is that move okay?

EDIT:  I think that the reason it is true is based upon the fact that $N=2m$.  Thus, when summing, your new starting point is now the root of unity exponent that is opposite the original root of unity exponent.  You are still summing over the same exponentials, but factoring out a $w_N^m$.  Does that seem reasonable?

Comment: You haven't told us what $w^a_b$ stands for.

Comment: oh, sorry.  $w_N=e^{\frac{2i\pi}{N}}$

Comment: I know that $w_N^m=-1$, but I'm not sure how we get it's alternating...

Comment: I'm not sure I believe the statement is true. What's the source?

Comment: a non published paper...i think since we are ultimately summing over powers of roots of unity that we can factor out a $-1$, , but I'm not sure.  As it is independent research, I can ask the author if i cna send.

Comment: I think the statement is true because of the fact that $N=2m$.  If you are summing roots of unity and you shift the starting root of unity to it's opposite, you can factor out a $-1=w_N^{mk}$.  Is this true?

Comment: is $k$ just an arbitrary integer?  There is no description for $k$; what it is, why it's there...You really don't need the coefficient $N..k!$ either as it has no bearing on the sum...

Comment: It has to be that $k<N$, Both $N,k\in \mathbb{N}$ with $N>1$.

Comment: Suggestion: take $m=3$, so $N=6$, take $k=1$ and $x=1$, and calculate both expressions. If they're not equal, you're done – you know the statement isn't true. If they are equal, maybe you get some idea of why the statement is true.

Answer (score 1):

Based upon the fact that $w_N=e^{\frac{2i\pi}{N}}$, look at the summation and forget the coefficient.  Also take note that since $w_N^N=1, w_N^m=-1$ since $N=2m$.  Now, you just factor out $w_N^{mk}$...
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}w_N^{-nk}e^{\frac{w_N^{n+m}}{N}x}& = w_N^{0\cdot k}e^{\frac{w_N^{m}}{N}x}+...+w_N^{(m-1)\cdot k}e^{\frac{w_N^{2m-1}}{N}x}+w_N^{m\cdot k}e^{\frac{w_N^{2m}}{N}x}+...+w_N^{(N-1)\cdot k}e^{\frac{w_N^{(N-1)+m}x}{N}}\\
& = w_N^{0\cdot k}e^{\frac{w_N^{m}}{N}x}+...+w_N^{(m-1)\cdot k}e^{\frac{w_N^{N-1}}{N}x}+w_N^{m\cdot k}e^{\frac{w_N^{0}}{N}x}+...+w_N^{(N-1)\cdot k}e^{\frac{w_N^{(N-1)+m}x}{N}}\\
& = w_N^{mk}\left[w_N^{m\cdot k}e^{\frac{w_N^{m}}{N}x}+...+w_N^{(N-1)\cdot k}e^{\frac{w_N^{N-1}}{N}x}+w_N^{0\cdot k}e^{\frac{w_N^{0}}{N}x}+...+w_N^{(m-1)\cdot k}e^{\frac{w_N^{m-1}x}{N}}\right]\\
& = w_N^{mk}\left[w_N^{0\cdot k}e^{\frac{w_N^{0}}{N}x}+...+w_N^{(m-1)\cdot k}e^{\frac{w_N^{m-1}x}{N}}+w_N^{m\cdot k}e^{\frac{w_N^{m}}{N}x}+...+w_N^{(N-1)\cdot k}e^{\frac{w_N^{N-1}}{N}x}\right]\\
& = w_N^{mk}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}w_N^{-nk}e^{\frac{w_N^{n}}{N}x}\\
& = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}w_N^{-nk}w_N^{mk}e^{\frac{w_N^{n}}{N}x}
\end{align}

And as you mentioned, you can simplify this even further since $w_N^m=-1$ you get 
$$N^{k-1}k!\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}w_N^{-nk}e^{\frac{w_N^{n+m}}{N}x}=N^{k-1}k!(-1)^k\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}w_N^{-nk}e^{\frac{w_N^{n}}{N}x}$$